# How to block BitTorrent in ASUS RT-AC88U

Tags: router, bittorrent, asus

I want to block BitTorrent with my ASUS RT-AC88U Wi-Fi router.

I already know that I have to block port 6681 through 6889. In Network Service Filter I can add blocks for ports, but I can only have 32 rules.

How do I input the range 6681 - 6889 into the rules? Dash is not an acceptable character for this, but I can enter a comma. However entering 6681,6889 results in error message "Please enter a value between 1 to 65535".

How can I effectively block BitTorrent with this router?

Comment: Bittorrent can be set to any arbitrary port - and dosen't really need an open port in some cases. Also, it might be helpful to add a screenshot of the UI

Comment: Disable UPNP in the router. If you leave it ON just about any software running on your local LAN can open whatever it wants on the router. Check the Connections tab on the SystemLog page in the router to see what is really open. (You may have some surprises.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most BitTorrent clients today can dynamically open ports in the router
using UPnP, so it's a simple matter for the user of the BitTorrent
client to configure a non-standard port-range and avoid your
firewall rule.

But for your question : The correct syntax for the range is
`6681:6889`.

Comment: Colon is the range separator for Asus routers. And good point about UPNP.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to setup [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/) onto the router and then use the web content filtering system and have **P2P/File sharing** checked. That would block a large number of domains, making it so the torrent client couldn't look up the IP of the tracker.

[image]

*(Which would only work if the torrent file for the tracker(s) isn't set to a IP address. But would also block a lot of the sites that host the torrent files as well.)*

On my RT-AC66U I use [DNSOmatic](https://dnsomatic.com/) for my DDNS and then use that to hook into my OpenDNS so I can also use DynDNS as well. Which would update both services with IP of the router, this way OpenDNS knows what rule set of filters to run for the DNS lookups.

Comment: Definitely would try this. Thank you for suggesting this.